# Adding an element to the NavigationBar

Tags: java, android, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

[image]

Is there any way to add an element to the navigation bar as seen in the picture?
I mean the fourth element you see.

[image]

Comment: Standard Android apps cannot do this, sorry.

Comment: The closest you can get is to implement a bottom bar of your own, right above this. But you cannot modify that navigation bar.

Comment: SwiftKey app as it does, I put an image to better understand.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is quite impossible to accompany more than three items into the bottom bar without distorting alignment int Standard Android apps.
Better make a linear layout with horizontal orientation. Or

You can use the method I mentioned below for stopping clustered menu items. You should call this method into "**onCreate**" method passing '**BottomNavigationView**'.

*// Method to disable Shifting Mode (Bottom Navigation)*

```
private void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            item.setShiftingMode(false);
            *//set once again checked value then view will be updated*
            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Could not get shift mode field!", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Sorry Can not change value!", e);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: SwiftKey app as it does, I put an image to better understand.